# How do I fork/exec a process which forwards all arguments in Rust?

Tags: rust, process, fork, exec

I want to write the following in Rust. I cannot figure out how to do this with Command API.

```sh
if [[ -z "${DEPLOY_ENV}" ]]; then
  $old_program "$@"
else
  $new_program "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) API is cross-platform and not all platforms have a concept of *exec* and *fork*. However, the standard library does provide the [`exec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html) method for `Command`s on Unix platforms via the `std::os::unix::process::CommandExt` extension trait.

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args_os().skip(1).collect();
    let err = Command::new("new_program")
        .args(&args)
        .exec();
    println!("Error: {}", err);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [fork](https://docs.rs/fork/0.1.18/fork/) crate:

```
use fork::{fork, Fork};

fn main() {
    // keeps the same arguments of course
    match fork() {
       Ok(Fork::Parent(child)) => println!("Continuing execution in parent process, new child has pid: {}", child),
       Ok(Fork::Child) => println!("I'm a new child process"),
       Err(_) => println!("Fork failed"),
    }
}
```

or the [exec](https://crates.io/crates/exec) crate:

```
use exec::Command;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args_os().skip(1).collect();
    let err = Command::new("new_program")
        .args(&args)
        .exec();
    println!("Error: {}", err);
}
```

Or if you're feeling up to it, call them more directly with the [nix](https://crates.io/crates/nix) or [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the process' arguments via `std::env::args_os` and pass them to a child process via `std::process::Command::args`.

For example:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::env::args_os;

fn main() {
    Command::new("cmd")
        .args(args_os())
        .output()
        .expect("cmd exited with error code");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will include the name of the Rust program, unlike the Bash `$@` construct. You might want to pass `args_os().skip(1)` instead.

Comment: Because of output() won't it wait for child process to finish? I just want to exec it (replace current process with that one)

Comment: You asked for fork/exec, not pure exec. I think that would warrant a separate question.